# Регулярное выражение для записи положительных действительных чисел с разделением запятой

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, qt

Хочу сделать регулярное выражение для записи нескольких положительных действительных чисел с разделением ", ", например, "120, 150.3, 1e10". 
У меня есть regEx для записи положительного действительного числа  `"^\\d+(\\.\\d+)?([eE][+-]?\\d+)?$"`. Понятно, что надо дописать `(\\,\\ )?` в конец.

Тут вопрос такой: как сделать отсечение введенных символов. Например, "120, 150.3, 1e10", ". Ввели запятую или запятую с пробелом, но числа дальше нет. Как отсечь запятую (и пробел)?

Comment: Вы используете `QRegularExpression`?

Comment: Да, задаю для валидатора

Comment: Я опубликовал ответ. Подходит? Если нет, объясните почему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

```
R"(^(\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?)(?:,\s(?1))*$)"
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/ZPoGVI/1).

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?)` - Захватывающая группа №1:

  - `\d+` - 1 и более цифр
  - `(?:\.\d+)?` - 1 или 0 повторов точки и 1 и более цифр
  - `(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?` - 1 или 0 повторов `e` / `E`, опциональных `+` или `-`, 1 и более цифр
- `(?:,\s(?1))*` - ноль и более повторов следующей последовательности шаблонов:

  - `,` - запятая
  - `\s` - пробельный символ
  - `(?1)` - весь шаблон группы №1
- `$` - конец строки.

Comment: Верно, спасибо. Подскажите ещё такой момент: если в QLineEdit установлен валидатор с RegEx, в какой момент срабатывает validate: в момент потери фокуса или ввода символа? Если последнее, то можно изменить на первое?

Comment: @ArseniySpiridonov В сети пишут, что при вводе символов, сам я не пробовал. Не знаю.